# How to effectively email someone to learn about a company I'm considering applying for?

Tags: job-search, email, contact

I found a developer on Stack Overflow whose profile lists his email and says to get in touch. He works for a company that I'm considering applying for, and I want to get a feel for what kinds of projects he works on and what the organization is like.

What is an effective way of cold-emailing him?

I feel that I should offer him something of value as an incentive for him to meet, but I can't think of what I could possibly offer him that he would find valuable seeing as how he is decades more experienced than I.

Should the fact that he listed his email with the phrase "get in touch" signal to me that he's expecting people to reach out to him about a potential job with his company? (in which case I shouldn't overthink it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should the fact that he listed his email with the phrase "get in touch" signal to me that he's expecting people to reach out to him about a potential job with his company? (in which case I shouldn't overthink it)

**Yes, you should not over-think this one.**

If some user includes their email on their SO profile and adds "get in touch" it is because that person *expects* or at least *hopes* that someone reaches out.

We don't know if that person will expect something in return yet, so I suggest you **get in touch first** in a general way and then ask that person if they would be kind enough to tell you how things are in the company, and that you are interested in a position there.

After that you will see what opportunities or compromises you can agree on and will be able to decide how to proceed.

Comment: And if they don't respond to the first email, respect that and move on.  Don't keep emailing "in case you didn't see my first email", because no one really believes that.